My Website Having Duplicate Category Titles On 1,2,3 pages
I am having issues with duplicate titles on my category pages. I am using the PH Creative Pro Theme and yoast plugin. you can see the diffences by checking these 2 urls :
https://gamerflare.com/monopoly-go/
https://gamerflare.com/monopoly-go/page/2/
i want to change the titles like “Monopoly Go – Page 1”.
please help me out.

Third party plugins are off topic for this Stack, see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. The best place for your question would be the plugin's support forum on wordpress.org
